# How can I specify the C++ version in VS Code's clangd?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, clangd

VS Code keeps recommending C++17 features in my C++14 project, such as

> Function xxx should be marked [[nodiscard]] (clang-tidy)

I tried setting this:

[image: clang-tidy extra args]

but this seems to be unrelated to the *clangd* extension which is installed in addition to *C/C++*. And as these clang-tidy hints briefly disappear when I restart clangd, I suspect they originate from that. How can I tell it to use C++14 for this project?

Comment: If you make your build system generate `compile_commands.json` (or do it yourself), Clangd will pick up all your compiler flags, not only `-std=c++20`.

Comment: What worked for me: create a `.clangd` file in the project's root dir containing `CompileFlags:
  Add: [-std=c++14]` (with a line break after the first colon).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks, also good to know. It turns out this is already generated but doesn't contain the C++ version because this project seems to rely on clang-5's default C++ version (although I find this very strange).